# How to use filters when importing on sas

Tags: sas

I have a very large data table on "dsv" format and i'm trying to import it on sas. However i don't have enough space to import the full table and then filter it (i've done this for smaller tables).

Is there any way to filter the data while importing it because at the end i will only use a part of that table ? If i want for example to import only rows that have the value 103 for Var2

PS: i'm using "proc import" not "data - infile..." because i don't know the exact number of columns

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A10 | 103 | Test |
| A02 | 102 | Hiis |
| ... | ... | .... |

Thank you

Comment: What is a DSV file?  Is that a delimited text file?

Comment: Yes delimited by the character "|"

Comment: PROC IMPORT will generate the code in the log, copy the code from the log and add the WHERE statement to it instead of using PROC IMPORT.

Comment: Show your full proc import code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `where` dataset option to the `out=` statement. For example:

```
proc import 
    file = 'myfile.txt' 
    out  = want(where=(var2=103))
    ...;
run;
```

Comment: I'v already tried this and i got an error : "var2 is not on file WORK.want"

Comment: It sounds like it's not reading in the column names as expected. You may need to review the output of the file first to be sure it's reading in the name row.

Comment: Thanks yes it was that. I was using the wrong variable type

Comment: To be precise, `where=` is a data set option, not a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can add dataset options to the dataset listed in the OUT= option of PROC IMPORT.

Example:

```
filename dsv temp;
data _null_;
  input (var1-var3) (:$20.);
  file dsv dsd dlm='|';
  put var1-var3;
cards;
Var1    Var2    Var3
A10 103 Test
A02 102 Hiis
;

proc import file=dsv dbms=csv out=want(where=(var2=102)) replace ;
  delimter='|';
run;
```

The result is a dataset with just one observation.

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 1 observations and 3 variables.
```

If you don't know the name of the second variable you could always just read the header row first and put the name into a macro variable.

```
data _null_;
  infile dsv dsd dlm='|' truncover obs=1;
  input (2*name) (:$32.);
  call symputx('var2',nliteral(name));
run;
proc import file=dsv dbms=csv out=want(where=(&var2=102)) replace ;
  delimter='|';
run;
```